# Creating a new object

Tags: java, swing, object, twitter, twitter4j

At the moment my program has a Jpanel with about 15 different inputs. These inputs are created to one long string called "searchInput".

"searchInput" is then put into a query named which then gets metadata about the tweet result one at a time, such as createdAt, user and text. These results are printed to a textArea named tweetsResult.

createdAt, user and text are only some of the metadata behind each tweet, more being favouriteCount and retweetCount.

Because Twitter has a maximum amount of Tweets it can deliver to you using the API, I feel it would be best if I created a new class which uses searchInput, and then get the desired amount of Tweets with all of the metadata into an object. And then from the main class, I would only call the results with the specific meta data that I would like.

Is this the right way to do it? If so how would I create this new object, presumably using getters and setters?

I hope this is clear to you, and many thanks for the help!

```
    List<Status> tweets = new ArrayList<Status>();

    //Standard Twitter and Twitter4j authentication
    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey);
    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
    Configuration configuration = builder.build();
    TwitterFactory twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
    Twitter twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(accessToken, accessTokenSecret));




    //The query is split up into 5 sections
    //All the text boxes are read in the seperate methods
    String searchWordInput = getWordSearchQuery();
    String searchPeopleInput = getPeopleSearchQuery();
    String filtersSearchInput = getFiltersSearchQuery();
    String dateAndLocationSearchInput = getDateAndLocationSearchQuery();
    String radiusAndLocationSearchInput = getRadiusAndLocationSearchQuery();
    String searchInput = searchWordInput + searchPeopleInput + filtersSearchInput + dateAndLocationSearchInput + radiusAndLocationSearchInput;
    //One big search String called "searchInput" is taken to be sent to Twitter
    //Increases maximum amount of tweets in one search
    int wantedTweets = 100; //CHANGE THIS FOR DIFFERENT AMOUNT OF TWEETS
    long lastSearchID = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    int remainingTweets = wantedTweets;
    Query query = new Query(searchInput);
    tweetsResultInput.append(searchInput);
    try {
        while (remainingTweets > 0) {
            remainingTweets = wantedTweets - tweets.size();
            if (remainingTweets > 100) {
                query.count(100);
            } else {
                query.count(remainingTweets);
            }
            QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
            tweets.addAll(result.getTweets());
            Status s = tweets.get(tweets.size() - 1);
            lastSearchID = s.getId();
            query.setMaxId(lastSearchID);
            remainingTweets = wantedTweets - tweets.size();
        }
        //Increases maximum amount of tweets in ones search


        tweetsResult.append(searchInput);
        tweetsResult.append("\n");
        //For the query tweets, using "searchInput", get every tweet in the format; when Tweet was sent, who it was sent by, and the Tweets text and write to tweetsResults
        for (Status tweet : tweets) {
            tweetsResult.append(tweet.getCreatedAt() + ":\t@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText());
            tweetsResult.append("\n");

        }
    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

Comment: What object are you trying to create? What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: The code above works fine, but I want to move all the Twitter stuff into a new class, and then from the main class call the specific metadata from the search.

Comment: **The code above works fine** - that's amazing **but I want to move all the Twitter stuff into a new class, and then from the main class call the specific metadata from the search**, then atleast you should try doing it first and let know of the errors you get in doing so?

Comment: Issue is I don't know how

Comment: Break every big problem to smaller ones. Can you put the functionality you want to move (refactor) into method / methods ? Moving methods is going to be easier